# OperationalError: near "?": syntax error python sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite3

Boa noite.

Estou tentando colocar uma coluna dinâmica com a função

```
class db():

    def __init__(self,coluna):
        self.coluna = coluna

    def inserir_coluna_tabela1(self):
        import sqlite3 as sql
        conn = sql.connect('db/dbase.db')

        cursor = conn.cursor()

        cursor.execute("""
        ALTER TABLE 'tabela01'
        ADD COLUMN ? 'TEXT NOT NULL'
        """, self.coluna)

        conn.commit()
        #
        print('Novo campo adicionado com sucesso.')
        #
        conn.close()

camponovo = db('2018')
camponovo.inserir_coluna_tabela1()
```

e está retornando o erro: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error

Obrigado!

Comment: Você não pode passar algo estrutural como parâmetro de _prepared statement_. Nesse caso, você deveria interpolar o valor de `self.coluna` na string de `ALTER TABLE`. As marcas de `?` só servem para DML, não servem para DDL

Comment: Obrigado! Fiz essa alteração e funcionou: cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE " + self.tabela +" ADD COLUMN '" + self.coluna +"' TEXT")

Comment: A resposta do jsbueno atende a sua pergunta. Creio que seja o adequada marcá-la como aceita

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A substituição de "?" (ou "%", "{}") em chamadas a drivers de SQL em Python, inclusive o SQLlite não funciona exatamente como a substituição de strings normal:

Essas chamadas só fazem a substituição de valores a serem inseridos, mas não substituem nomes de colunas, tabelas ou clausulas de SQL - elas são desenhadas de forma que "entendem"  a estrutura do SQL, e fazem automaticamente a inserção e o escape de aspas simples - `'` - quando necessário, de forma a impedir SQL injection.

Nesse caso o que você deve fazer é usar a substituição normal de strings do Python, com o `.format` se for uma versão abaixo da 3.6, ou com as f-strings - e deixar a substituição que é provida pela chamada a `exectute` só para os valores mesmo:

```
 cursor.execute(f"""
        ALTER TABLE 'tabela01'
        ADD COLUMN '{self.coluna}' 'TEXT NOT NULL'
        """)
```

Ou, se for até o Python 3.5:

```
 cursor.execute("""
        ALTER TABLE 'tabela01'
        ADD COLUMN '{}' 'TEXT NOT NULL'
        """.format(self.coluna))
```